How to put prime before value during a substitution?
Here is a sample Mathematica code:
coordrep = {t -> t[τ], r -> r[τ], θ -> θ[τ], ϕ -> ϕ[τ]};

lagrangian = -(f[r, rh] t'^2 - r'^2/f[r, rh] - r^2 θ'^2 + r^2 n^2 Sin[θ]^2) /. coordrep

I wish to have, for example, t'[τ] and similar elements in the result instead of what the output is. How do you go about doing that?

As long as things don't start to complicate too much, you can do another replacement: /. Derivative[n__][x_[τ]] :> Derivative[n][x][τ]. But do be careful in general, as explained by @evanb.

One approach to get your desired result, of course, is to just put the time dependence explicitly,
lagrangian = -(f[r, rh]  t'[τ]^2 - r'[τ]^2/f[r, rh] - r[τ]^2  θ[τ]'^2 + 
    r[τ]^2  n^2  Sin[θ[τ]]^2)

This is probably the most straightforward approach, especially if you go beyond 1 independent coordinate (since then ' is ambiguous).
It's helpful to see why that's probably the most straightforward approach by looking at the FullForm of a piece of your Lagrangian.  Let's just take the first term,
FullForm[f[r, rh]  t'^2]
(* Times[f[r,rh],Power[Derivative[1][t],2]] *)

Roughly speaking, the FullForm is the internal representation that Mathematica uses for pattern matching and substitution.  Note that Derivative is a little peculiar-looking, in that it has two sets of square brackets.  The first set of square brackets indicate which slots of the following function are to be differentiated (in this case t only has one slot, where it takes τ), and the second is the function itself.
Derivative is designed this way to naturally act as an operator on functions.  It takes a function and returns another function, which can then be evaluated.
One simple example reveals the issue
Derivative[1][Sin[x]]
(* Sin[x]' *)

What went wrong?  Sin[x] is not a function.  It is a value!  It is the value of the function Sin evaluated at the parameter x.  Instead, what you want to do is
Derivative[1][Sin][x]
(* Cos[x] *)

THREE sets of square brackets?  The way to understand it is Derivative[1] is an operator which takes a function and returns a function.  So Derivative[1][Sin] gives Cos.  The final square brackets just apply the result (that is, Cos) to the argument(s).
The reason your substitution rule is not producing what you expect is that your coordrep replaces the symbols with values, not with functions.  If you want to write a short-hand Lagrangian without the variable dependence then you need to be careful to handle the Derivative case as well.
